# Combing datasets in R: vector of letters for rbind

Tags: r

I have few datasets that I want to combine in one. I have imported them with the names `{a,b,c,....o}`.

Now I want to rbind them together to a single datasets. I could do `rbind(a,b,c,....o)`. However, I wanted to do it more elgantly; I tried `rbind(factor(letters[1:15]))`. Doesn't work.

I guess my difficulty stems from my lack of knowledge of the classes in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column names are same for all the datasets, we can use `mget` to get the dataset in a 'list', `rbind` the list elements using `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, mget(letters[1:15]))
```

Or another option would be `rbindlist` from `data.table`.  This would also work with different column names.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(letters[1:15]))
```

In general, if you have a lot of datasets, it may be better to read the files into a list i.e.

```
files <- list.files() #assuming all files are in the working directory
lst <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE) #or `fread` from data.table
```